# Battery level indicator doesn't work, what did I do wrong?

Tags: arduino, batteries, code

I am building a battery level indicator. I am using a Arduino Uno and a voltage sensor. I am currently trying to write the code for this project, but I always get 103.5%, regardless of what the voltage of the battery is. I checked the voltage measuring part of the code a few times, so the problem shouldn't lie there. I am new to programming so I don't know where my mistake could be.

This is the code I am using to calculate the battery level

```
float Messwert;
float Spannung;
float x;
float Batterieladung;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Messwert = analogRead(1);
  Spannung = map(Messwert, 0, 1023, 0, 250);
  x= Spannung / 10;

  if (x<0.4){
    Serial.println(0); 
  } else {
    Batterieladung = 103.5 / (1 + (4.333 * pow(5.530, -5.805 * x)));
    Serial.println(Batterieladung, 2);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

I would really appreciate it if anybody had an idea of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So what is the Batterieladung calculation supposed to do?  Wouldn't it be better to map 0 to 1023 to your Batterieladung variable.

Comment: Please, don't assume anyone on this site knows German. I understand you are a newbie, but if you want to improve your skills in this trade learn to write your code using English names and comments. Moreover, you should always show a schematic and maybe a photo of your setup. Why do you assume the problem lies in the code and not in the hardware (did you check you wired the sensor correctly? Did you check the sensor works?). I'm not saying your code is necessarily bug-free, but in embedded systems you must never rule out a hardware problem without checking first.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine nah, forcing people to program in English is bad. There are only a handful of variable names here. I'll even save you the effort of looking them up:

Comment: Messwert=measurement value, Spannung=voltage, x=x, Batterieladung=battery charge

Comment: @user253751 Thanks, but no need to do that effort. I know German at a discrete level. It's not "forcing" people, is gaining a skill that will be extremely useful in the future. English is the de-facto standard for scientific and technical communication. Software (in source form) is also a mean of communication between humans. If you don't learn to use English, your code will be harder to read by non-native speaker. This may be ok if you work in a company with no international contacts, but it is overly restrictive. Some companies could even refuse to hire you if you can't code in English.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine We should all program in Chinese, to be future-proof. After all, Chinese companies (which are going to be designing all the electronics in the future) won't hire you if you can't code in Chinese.

Comment: @user253751 Moreover, a program not using English could have a worse time being audited or debugged by external institutions. Another scenario: a company from another country want's to buy your system for big bucks, source code included. If the code is not in English, it could be quite a liability in getting the deal done.

Comment: @user253751 Please, tone down the sarcasm. I'm not trying to be provocative here, but I'm just stating well-known facts in the industry. We could argue ad infinitum about why and how English became the de-facto bridge language of science and tech. BTW, if you go on Chinese websites and browse for datasheets in a language different than Chinese, you only find them in English (if any). And BTW, if the OP wanted to find a job in China, yes, I would advise him to learn Chinese.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your trouble is here:

```
Batterieladung = 103.5 / (1 + (4.333 * pow(5.530, -5.805 * x)));
```

\$ 5.530^{-5.805x} \$ will range from 2.77 × 10<sup>-22</sup> for x = 5 to 1.63 × 10<sup>-108</sup> for x = 25. The divisor for that line of the program will always be '1' so the result will be 103.5 for all values.

Comment: I am really grateful for your help. I will look further into that advice.